# Does forecast error variance decomposition in which the response variable predominately explains itself imply the model is incorrectly specified?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, vector-autoregression

So I have set up a six variable VAR model in the hope of explain natural gas prices and performed forecast error variance decomposition, however the response variable (natural gas prices) explains itself.

Does this mean that the model is incorrectly specified and that an alternative approach is necessary.

My results are as follows,

[image]

where each variable respresents an impulse and the response variable is natural gas prices.